Interruptores y Delay
Tengo una duda, tengo este codigo, yo necesito que al presionar el interruptor del puerto A (El RA0) vaya decreciendo el valor de COUNT. Si no pongo el btfss funciona, pero si lo pongo se queda parpadeando el RB7 y jamas decrece.
Claramente uso RA0 y RA1 como entradas, por ahora solo el RA0 para decrecer y el puerto B para asignar las salidas.
La segunda parte es esta, cada vez que agrego un call Delay mas, me va apagando LEDS!! es decir, si pongo 1 call Delay mas donde lo ven, ahora  el LED de RB0 no prende y es decir, no entiendo, por que pasa eso??? si pongo 2 call Delay, ahora de RB0 a RB3 digamos, deja de encender
Ayuda con estas dos cosas por amor de todo
STATUS  equ 03h
TRISA   equ 85h
PORTA   equ 05h
TRISB   equ 86h
PORTB   equ 06h
PCL equ 02h
COUNT1  equ 20h
COUNT2  equ 21h
COUNT   equ 0x23
    
;*****  Inicializando programa ************
    org 0x00
    bsf STATUS, 5           ; Cambiamos a bank1.
    movlw b'00000011'
    movwf TRISA         ; Asigno - entradas - bits RA0 y RA1 - puerto A.
    clrf TRISB              ; Asigno - salida todos los bits - puerto B. 
    bcf STATUS, 5           ; Cambiamos a bank0.
    
    clrf PORTB

;*****  Instruccion principal ************
    movlw 07h
Main
    movwf COUNT
    call table
    movwf PORTB
  ;------------------;
    call Delay
    call Delay
  ;------------------;
;    btfss PORTA, 0 ; Si es 0 ejecuta la instruccion
;   goto Main
  ;------------------; 
    decf COUNT, 1
    movf COUNT, 0
    goto Main
        
;*****  Subrutinas del programa ************
    
Delay   
Loop1   decfsz COUNT1,1
    goto Loop1
    decfsz COUNT2,1
    goto Loop1
  return
    
table
    
    addwf PCL, f            ; Agrego el valor al PCL
    retlw   b'00000001' ; RB0
    retlw   b'00000010' ; RB1
    retlw   b'00000100' ; RB2
    retlw   b'00001000' ; RB3
    retlw   b'00010000' ; RB4
    retlw   b'00100000' ; RB5
    retlw   b'01000000' ; RB6
    retlw   b'10000000' ; RB7
    return
;*****  Fin del programa ************
    end




La etiqueta [tag:assembly] pide que se acompañe con la etiqueta del procesador o conjunto de instrucciones para el que estás programando, ya que el ensamblador cambia de uno a otro. Pasa el ratón sobre la etiqueta o haz clic en ella para más información.
